# XAML Changing font size dynamically iOS Xamarin app

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to make a label appear the same size proportionally regardless of the resolution of the target device

I have the following code

```
<StackLayout 
     Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" 
     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
         <Label Text="{Binding AccountName}" 
                Style="{StaticResource labelStylePrimaryBold}"
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

I have the above code and this in my App.xaml

```
  <Style x:Key="labelStylePrimaryBold" TargetType="Label">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#414042" />
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
  </Style>
```

I need to make this available across my app, I've seen the following code on 
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts/

```
label.FontSize = Device.OnPlatform (
     24,
     Device.GetNamedSize (NamedSize.Medium, label),
     Device.GetNamedSize (NamedSize.Large, label)
);
```

But my label does not have an ID, how would I go about linking this up?

I'm very new to Xamarin, but this seems like a fairly obvious thing to want to do.

Comment: The link contains the code to do this in Xaml. But if you still want to do it in your backend code, use `X:Name` to add an id to your Label.

Comment: I cannot see the code to do the font size in  XAML ? I need it in App.xaml too ?

Comment: `<Label.FontSize>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="10" Android="11" WinPhone="12" />
    </Label.FontSize>` You can use this in xaml.

Comment: that mentions different platforms, I need iphone 4, iphone 5, ipad 2 etc.

Comment: Well to do that you will probably need to check the width and height of the screen to determine the phone. I answered a similar question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096347/how-in-xamarin-forms-project-use-different-sizes-of-backgroundimage-property-for/38096673#38096673 ...

Comment: In xaml we also have one way but that will distinguish between Tablet and Phone i.e. `<Label.FontSize><OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"><OnIdiom.Phone><OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="10" /></OnIdiom.Phone><OnIdiom.Tablet><OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="20" /></OnIdiom.Tablet></OnIdiom></Label.FontSize>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Xamarin forms **[NamedSize Enumeration](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.NamedSize/)**

You can choose from:

- Default
- Large
- Medium
- Micro
- Small

Example:

```
<Label  FontSize="small"  Text="Joe"></Label>
<Label  FontSize="Large"  Text="Joe"></Label>
```